# Copy-paste not working between MS office and Apple apps

Tags: ms-office, pages, copy-paste

MacBookPro
Sonoma 14.1.2
Microsoft Word for Mac 16.80 (23121017)

Copy-paste has stopped working between MS office (especially Word) and Apple apps.
Neither direction works.

I can copy-paste between MS Office documents.
I can copy-paste between anything in the Apple ecosystem.

(I only have to use MS Office apps because of work.  Never liked them much.)

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Do any of the solutions in the "Related" threads on the right apply?

Comment: Suggest you add version of Word to question.

Comment: Copy and Paste between Pages and Word 2021 (v16.83) works fine for me. In Apple's apps, does "Paste and Match Style" work? And in MS apps, the same, or Paste Special > Unformatted text?

Comment: @LincD. - I spent quite some time reviewing other threads on the site and have found nothing analagous.

Comment: What changed right before it happened? Any upgrades of anything? As an analysis step: can you create a new user on your Mac, log in and try whether it works there?

Comment: Do you copy by using a key command or by selecting from the Edit menu? If only one, try the other. Any difference? Also, have you rebooted since this started? If not try that. In fact, try booting in safe mode. Test and then reboot as usual.

Comment: @LincD. - The problem occurs in all ways that I try to copy-paste, no difference.  I have rebooted.  Yet to try safe mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue with brute force:

- Removed MS Office
- Update macOS to Sonoma 14.4
- Reinstalled MS Office.